# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}{1\over i + 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

The problem is to evaluate the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}{1\over i + 1}$$

First, I attempted using double sum notation and applied the Binomial Theorem to get
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}{1\over i + 1}
&= \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(-1)^j{1\over m + 1} \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{- 1\over m + 1}
\end{align}
Claim: $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}{-1 \over m + 1} = {1-n\over n}$.
This holds for $n = 2$. Proceeding by induction on $n$, suppose that $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}{1\over m + 1} = {n-1\over n}$ holds for some $n > 2$. Then we want to show that
$\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}{1\over m + 1} = {n\over n + 1}$. Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^n{1\over m + 1} &= \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} {1\over m + 1} + {1\over n + 1} \\
&= {n-1 \over n} + {1\over n + 1} \\
&= {n\over n + 1}
\end{align}
as desired. Therefore,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}{1\over i + 1} = {1-n \over n}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to verify if your work is correct?

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $\frac{1-n}{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the OP's identity $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}(-1)^i \frac{1}{i+1} = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{j}(-1)^j\frac{1}{m+1}$ as I don't see how it follows from the binomial theorem.

On the other hand, you can certainly use the binomial theorem to sum the given expression:
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^1(1-x)^{n-1} \mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^1 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}(-1)^i x^i \mathrm{d}x \\ 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}(-1)^i\frac{1}{i+1} 
\end{split}
$$
Since $\int_0^1(1-x)^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^1 t^{n-1} \mathrm{d}t=1/n$ (changing variables from $x$ to $t=1-x$) it follows that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}(-1)^i\frac{1}{i+1} = \frac{1}{n}-1 = \frac{1-n}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

A direct computation is possible.  Note$$\binom{n-1}{i} \frac{1}{1+i} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(i+1)! \, (n-i-1)!} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{n!}{(i+1)! \, (n-(i+1))!} = \frac{1}{n} \binom{n}{i+1}.$$

Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^i \binom{n-1}{i} \frac{1}{i+1} 
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i+1} \\
&= -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=2}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( (-1)^0 \binom{n}{0} + (-1)^1 \binom{n}{1} - \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left(1 - n + (1+(-1))^n\right) \\
&= \frac{1-n}{n},
\end{align}$$
where we have used the binomial theorem $$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} a^{n-i} b^i = (a+b)^n$$ with the choice $a = 1$, $b = -1$.

---

As for your computation, you got the right answer, but there are some problems with your work.  Your introduction of a double summation is incorrect, which you can see by noting that the outer sum ranges from $m = 1$ to $n-1$, but this doesn't depend on $i$ in any way, so it cannot replace $\frac{1}{i+1}$.  Then the induction is also incorrect.  Your claim
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{-1}{m+1} = \frac{1-n}{n}$$ does not hold; e.g., $n = 3$ would imply $$-\frac{5}{6} = \frac{-1}{2} + \frac{-1}{3} = \frac{1-3}{3} = -\frac{2}{3},$$ which is false.  The problem is that the inductive step is wrong:  $$\frac{n-1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n(n+1)} + \frac{\color{red}{n}}{n(n+1)} = \frac{n^2 + n - 1}{n(n+1)}.$$